# Glide package manager usage

Tags: go, glide-golang

I'm using [Glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide) to manage my golang dependencies, but when trying to build my project on a clean environment, the `vendor` directory is being ignore:

```
./glide install
[INFO]  Downloading dependencies. Please wait...
[INFO]  --> Found desired version locally github.com/dustin/go-humanize 7a41df006ff9af79a29f0ffa9c5f21fbe6314a2d!
[INFO]  --> Found desired version locally github.com/jaxxstorm/flexvolume b65378104ef0f49af77d6f73d87da7e78d0f8252!
[INFO]  --> Found desired version locally github.com/kolyshkin/goploop-cli 5365b446a713e31ac4f2026b05a6dac27bbdf21c!
[INFO]  --> Found desired version locally github.com/urfave/cli 0bdeddeeb0f650497d603c4ad7b20cfe685682f6!
[INFO]  Setting references.
[INFO]  --> Setting version for github.com/kolyshkin/goploop-cli to 5365b446a713e31ac4f2026b05a6dac27bbdf21c.
[INFO]  --> Setting version for github.com/dustin/go-humanize to 7a41df006ff9af79a29f0ffa9c5f21fbe6314a2d.
[INFO]  --> Setting version for github.com/urfave/cli to 0bdeddeeb0f650497d603c4ad7b20cfe685682f6.
[INFO]  --> Setting version for github.com/jaxxstorm/flexvolume to b65378104ef0f49af77d6f73d87da7e78d0f8252.
[INFO]  Exporting resolved dependencies...
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/urfave/cli
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/jaxxstorm/flexvolume
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/dustin/go-humanize
[INFO]  --> Exporting github.com/kolyshkin/goploop-cli
[INFO]  Replacing existing vendor dependencies
```

All the vendor deps are there

```
vendor
└── github.com
    ├── dustin
    │   └── go-humanize
    ├── jaxxstorm
    │   └── flexvolume
    ├── kolyshkin
    │   └── goploop-cli
    └── urfave
        └── cli
            ├── altsrc
        └── autocomplete
```

11 directories

but my project still ignores the vendor dir:

```
go build -o ploop main.go
    main.go:4:2: cannot find package "github.com/jaxxstorm/flexvolume" in any of:
        /usr/lib/golang/src/github.com/jaxxstorm/flexvolume (from $GOROOT)
        /tmp/go/src/github.com/jaxxstorm/flexvolume (from $GOPATH)
    main.go:7:2: cannot find package "github.com/kolyshkin/goploop-cli" in any of:
        /usr/lib/golang/src/github.com/kolyshkin/goploop-cli (from $GOROOT)
        /tmp/go/src/github.com/kolyshkin/goploop-cli (from $GOPATH)
    main.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/urfave/cli" in any of:
        /usr/lib/golang/src/github.com/urfave/cli (from $GOROOT)
        /tmp/go/src/github.com/urfave/cli (from $GOPATH)
```

I don't think I need to set `GOVENDOREXPERIMENT` because I'm using `go1.7.4`

Comment: You're not building a package, your just building a single file. Build or install your package by its import path, or from within the main package directory.

Comment: Sorry, not following here, can you elaborate?

Comment: Type `go build full/import/path` or just `go build` from within your project.

Comment: That made no difference I'm afraid :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very stupid really, the git repo also needs to be in the`$GOPATH`. I symlinked my repo to `$GOPATH/src/github.com/vendor/project` and everything worked.

Comment: Don't use a symlink in your GOPATH. Symlinks are ignored by the build tools in many cases. Just follow the documentation: https://golang.org/doc/code.html